# php echo statement div class

Tags: php, css, class, html, echo

```
<?php $lname = $_POST['lname'];
   if ( isset($_POST['lname'] )&& !empty( $_POST['lname'] ) ) {
      echo '<div class="result"My blank is under</div> <div class="green"> $lname </div> ';
   } else {
      echo '<div class="result">Please tell them your</div> <div class="green">last name!</div> ';
   }
?>
```

The syntax should be correct however when i enter the data into my form the echo statement displays the variable name $lname in the green class not the data entered.

Did i forget quotes somewhere or to escape somewhere?

```
<style>
    .result {
        color: #FFF;
        display: block;
        font-size: 36px;
        margin-top: 1px;
        margin-before: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-start: 0; 
        margin-end: 0;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight: bold; }
    .green {
        color: #C9FF1F;
        display: block;
        font-size: 40px;
        margin-top: 1px;
        margin-before: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-start: 0;
        margin-end: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User below code, it will solve your problem.

   <?php 
   $lname = $_POST['lname'];
   if ( isset($_POST['lname'] ) && !empty( $_POST['lname'] ) ) {
      echo '<div class="result">My blank is under </div> <div class="green"> '.$lname.'   </div> ';
   } else {
      echo '<div class="result">Please tell them your</div> <div class="green">last name!</div> ';
   }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables are not interpolated with single-quote strings in PHP; if you want that functionality, you need to do something like this:

`echo "Hello $name";`

Instead of

`echo 'Hello $name';`

If you want to use single quotes, concatenate your string, as such:

`echo 'Hello ' . $name;`

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
echo '<div class="result"My blank is under</div> <div class="green">' . $lname . '</div> ';}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this............

```
<?php $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    if ( isset($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['lname'])) { ?>
    <div class="result">My blank is under</div> <div class="green"><?php echo $lname ?></div> ';
 <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="result">Please tell them your</div> <div class="green">last name!</div> ';
<?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="do-info">
      <div class=WINER">+ ,0<span id="regalo">0</span> DOMM</div>
  </div>

  <div id="do-info2">
      <div class="WINER2">Mañana  DOOM</div>
  </div>
```

OLA BUEN DIA quisiera saber como le puedo hacer para que el winner uno me pase mas de un resultado  a la vez o si se puede repetir infinidad de veces

Comment: Please provide your answer in proper English.